# PCI mmio allocating different address from lspci

Tags: kernel, linux-device-driver, pci

I am looking into my PCI driver for Ethernet NIC.

This is my code

```c
int rc = pcim_enable_device(pdev);
... 
abc = ffs(pci_select_bars(pdev, IORESOURCE_MEM))-1;

if (pci_resource_len(pdev, abc) < 256) {
    dev_err(&pdev->dev, "Invalid PCI region size(s), aborting\n");
    return -ENODEV;
}

rc = pcim_iomap_regions(pdev, BIT(abc), "modinfo");

void *mmio_addr = pcim_iomap_table(pdev)[abc];
printk("%x\n", mmio_addr);
```

In above line `mmio_addr` is not what shown in `lspci -vvv` command I believe `pcim_iomap_regions()` gives the address of MMIO which can be seen in `lspci` command output in dmesg I am getting `0x8006d000` but my MMIO region 2 and 3 are `c0404000` & `c0400000`. Why is that? My my PCI Ethernet driver its really my module that as mentioned as kernel driver for Ethernet PCI.

Comment: mmio_addr is a virtual address. lspci shows physical addresses.

Comment: `pci_resource_start(pdev, abc)` should match the physical address as seen in the lspci command output.